# How to create custom pin code view in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to create pin code view like below image , created custom text for design pin code view but unable to create like below image:

[image]

code Which i Implemented:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:upstanders/global/theme/colors.dart';
import 'package:upstanders/global/widgets/buttons.dart';
import 'package:upstanders/register/view/view.dart';
import 'package:upstanders/register/widgets/widgets.dart';

class CreatePasscodeForm extends StatelessWidget {
  TextEditingController pin1Controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController pin2Controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController pin3Controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController pin4Controller = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
      width: size.width,
      height: size.height,
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30, top: 20),
      child: Expanded(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              "Enter your passcode",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: MyTheme.white,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  height: 2.000,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.06),
            _pinRowInputs(),
            Expanded(
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                  child: RoundedBorderTextButton(
                    title: "CREATE",
                    height: size.height * 0.06,
                    width: size.width / 2.7,
                    bgColor: MyTheme.primaryColor,
                    textColor: MyTheme.secondryColor,
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => AddProfileScreen()));
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _pinRowInputs() {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: PinCodeTextField(
            controller: pin1Controller,
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: PinCodeTextField(
            controller: pin2Controller,
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: PinCodeTextField(
            controller: pin3Controller,
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: PinCodeTextField(
            controller: pin4Controller,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

pin_code_text_field.dart :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PinCodeTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController controller;
  

  const PinCodeTextField({Key key, this.controller, })
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
      width: size.width / 5.5,
      height: size.height * 0.09,
      child: Container(
       padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
       alignment: Alignment.center,
        
       child: TextFormField(
         obscureText: true,
         maxLength: 1,
         style: TextStyle(
           color: Colors.white,
           fontSize:30),
         keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
         textAlign: TextAlign.center,
         controller: controller,
         decoration: InputDecoration(
             filled: true,
            //  fillColor: Colors.white,
             counterText: "",
             border: InputBorder.none
              // border: new OutlineInputBorder(
              // borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
              //   const Radius.circular(15.0),
              // ))
              ),
            
          
         validator: (value) {
           if (value.isEmpty) {
           
             return null;
           }
          
           return null;
         },
       ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

Comment: Where is the call to get the key pad ? I can't find one. Just the call to get pin Row is there.

Comment: Just want textfield pin code view, please ingore keypad for now.

Comment: How you show numbers without typing them ? This feature can't work as single piece. You need to call setState for pincode row for every key you press on your designed keypad.  Try looking some other flutter apps on GitHub who has this their custom pin code screen or just use any package.

Answer (score -1):

First thing you might be needing is *autofocus=true* in text field, and a make custom keyboard for your design.

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Will use comments for things like this. P.S for Comments need 50 rep